# How do I launch a file with the extension .darwin.amd64?

Tags: file

How do I launch or open a file with the extension .darwin.amd64?

Double clicking it results in: "There is no application available to open the document..."

Comment: What is the full filename and where did it come from?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  What program/application/document are you trying to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no file extension, then it is most likely **Mach-O** file format. This kind of files without file extension can be executed within terminal by dragging the file to the terminal window and pressing enter. Another way is to use terminal to `cd` into the directory containing the file, and executing `./filename.darwin.amd64`, of course replace *filename* with your actual filename.